# keras, sparse_categorical_crossentropy label Y dimension and value range

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Can someone please explain dimensionality logic for input X and class Y
for `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss function ?

I checked both Keras and tf2 doc and examples, and this post.
[Cross Entropy vs Sparce](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326065/cross-entropy-vs-sparse-cross-entropy-when-to-use-one-over-the-other) but one point is not clear to me.

Does the Y vector need to be expanded to the same number column as
the number classes models outputs (if I use softmax output), or
Does Keras automatically expand Y?

In my case, I have input images 32x32, and Y is a number between 0 and 10.
So the input is (batch_size,  h, w),  Y (batch_size, 0....10 integer value)

```
X = (73257, 32, 32)
Y = (73257, 1)
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=30, validation_split=0.10, batch_size=1, verbose=True)
```

The model itself just a Sequential bunch of Dense layers and output Softmax.

```
model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu',
                    input_shape=input_shape,
                    kernel_initializer='he_uniform',
                    bias_initializer='ones'))
# bunch of Dense layer and output softmax
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

The error is dimensionality.

```
ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (1, 1)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (1, 32, 10)).
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [that](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326065/cross-entropy-vs-sparse-cross-entropy-when-to-use-one-over-the-other) post, both `categorical cross-entropy (cce)` and `sparse categorical cross-entropy (scc)` have the same loss function just except the format of the true label `Y`. Simply if `Y` is an integer, you would use `scc` whereas if `Y` is one-hot, you would use `cce`. So for `scc`, ground truth `Y` is mostly `1D` whereas in `cce`, ground truth `Y` mostly is `2D`. For ground truth

```
- (num_of_samples, n_class_one_hot_encode) <- for cce (2D)
- (num_of_samples, n_class_int) <- for scc (1D)
```

For example, if we use the `cifar10` data set, we can do

```
import tensorflow as tf

(x_train, y_train), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# train set / data 
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255

sparse = y_train
onehot = y_train

onehot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(onehot , num_classes=10)

print(sparse[:5]) # < --- (num_of_samples, n_class_int)
print(onehot[:5]) # < --- (num_of_samples, n_class_one_hot_encode)

[[6]
 [9]
 [9]
 [4]
 [1]]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Now, let's define a simple model and train using the above both and see what happens.

```
def net():
    input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu")(input)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(input, x)
    return model
```

Using `cce`

```
model = net()
model.compile(
          loss  = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
          metrics = 'accuracy',
          optimizer = 'adam')

his = model.train_on_batch(x_train, onehot, return_dict=True)
print(his)
{'loss': 2.376708984375, 'accuracy': 0.09651999920606613}

one_hot_pred = model.predict(x_train)

print(onehot[0])
print(one_hot_pred[0])

print(onehot[0].shape)
print(one_hot_pred[0].shape)
```

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
[0.1516315  0.1151238  0.11732318 0.10644271 0.08946694 0.1398355
 0.05046898 0.04249624 0.11813554 0.06907552]
(10,)
(10,)
```

Now, using `scc`

```
model = net()
model.compile(
          loss  = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
          metrics = 'accuracy',
          optimizer = 'adam')
 
his = model.train_on_batch(x_train, sparse, return_dict=True)
print(his)
{'loss': 2.331458806991577, 'accuracy': 0.10066000372171402}

sparse_pred = model.predict(x_train)

print(sparse[0])
print(sparse_pred[0])

print(sparse[0].shape)
print(sparse_pred[0].shape)
```

```
[6]
[0.07184976 0.08837385 0.06910037 0.12347631 0.09542189 0.09981853
 0.11247937 0.06707954 0.14902702 0.12337337]
(1,)
(10,)
```

Observe that, `gt` and `pred` shape for `scc` are `(1,)` and `(10,)`.  In this case, the loss computes the logarithm only for output index which ground truth indicates to. For example, the `gt` here is `6`, and from `pred` the loss will compute only the logarithm of `pred[6]`. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/503788/209125) are some little more details of it.

Comment: Thank you very much.   Yeah in my case root cause was I had flattened the initial input level.  I had only adjusted the index so it in the range 0... 9 vs 1 to 10